# PHPmailer does not send email and issues no errors

Tags: phpmailer

I know this question has been asked before and I have implemented all the suggestions I could find without success.
Before I give up on PHPmailer and use the cryptic PHP mail, which does work, I thought maybe somewhere out there in the world may have a solution.

**PHP**

```
<?php
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';

function sendEmail($subject, $body, $toEmail, $fromEmail, $fromName = 'N/A', $isHTML=false, $msg="Thank you for contacting us. Your message has been sent.")
{
    try 
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host      = 'mail.privateemail.com';
        $mail->Port      = '465';
        $mail->SMTPAuth  = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username  = 'admin@writers-tryst.com';              // SMTP username
        $mail->Password  = 'MYPWD'; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->From      = $fromEmail;
        $mail->FromName  = $fromName;
        $mail->Subject   = $subject;
        if ($isHTML) $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Body      = $body;
        $mail->AddAddress($toEmail);
        $result = $mail->Send() ? 1 : 0;
        if (count($msg)) echo $msg;
        return $result;
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
          return $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
          return $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: in class.phpmailer.php class is `$mail->From` and `$mail->FromName` are separate functions or  same like this `$this->mail->SetFrom($from_email,$from_name);`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can they not be set separately as I have done?

Comment: You may need to look into DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail). Your email may be sent but then filtered out. Have you setup your DKIM yet?

Comment: "All the suggestions I could find"; you didn't look very hard. You're using an old version, have based your code on an obsolete example and you have not read even the readme, let alone the troubleshooting docs that PHPMailer provides. If mail() works, try just skipping the call to issmtp() as then PHPMailer will use mail() too.

Comment: Add 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
and give us the output. It show more info about the server and the connection

Answer (score 0):

Try add:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2
```

Only for debugging and for getting more information about the connection.
And Add:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
)
```

This code help you to get a more secure connection.